# Add annotation to all Django ORM queries that go through a model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

The Django AbstractUser has fields for `first_name` and `last_name`, and `get_full_name` method.

If I wanted to filter Users based on a search of their full name, I can add a custom model manager for the User, that has a method something like this:

```
def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    if any(key for key in kwargs if key.startswith('full_name')):
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            full_name=Concat(models.F('first_name'), models.Value(' '), models.F('last_name'))
        )
    return queryset.filter(*args, **kwargs)
```

Meaning I can do things like:

```
User.objects.filter(full_name='Foo Bar')
User.objects.filter(full_name__icontains='foo b')
... etc
```

But of course this will only work when directly filtering Users above.  If you have Post objects that are FK'd to a User, then you get this:

```
Post.objects.filter(user__full_name='Foo Bar')
...
FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: full_name
```

**So the question is, is there a way** (without modifying all models to have custom managers), **to allow Django to always recognise a given term (in this case 'full_name') on all joins to a given model's table, and annotate the necessary value so it can be filtered on**?

*Note: I'm aware I could of course add `full_name` as a field on the user, and try to ensure that it's always up to date, but I'm specifically trying not to add this denormalised data to the db.*

Comment: It seems it's not possible based from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Model._base_manager)

Comment: Specifically this statement: ```Base managers aren’t used when querying on related models, or when accessing a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship. For example, if the Question model from the tutorial had a deleted field and a base manager that filters out instances with deleted=True, a queryset like Choice.objects.filter(question__name__startswith='What') would include choices related to deleted questions.```

Comment: You could probably just do something like `Post.objects.filter(user__in=filtered_and_annotated_user_queryset)`